# Vacuum expectation value in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum

In QFT, one writes the VEV of a field $\psi$ as $\langle0|\psi|0\rangle$. But as I understand it, the fields in QFT are not operators, but just some functions which we use to calculate cross-sections. What does one mean by bra-keting it in such a way as if $\psi$ is an operator?

(Edit: a field in QFT is also a solution of the equation of motion, of course.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But as I understand it, the fields in QFT are not operators,

I'm not sure where you heard that, but quantum fields *are* operators. Or more precisely, operator-valued functions of position: a quantum field $\psi$ maps every point in space, $\mathbf{x}$, to an operator, $\psi(\mathbf{x})$.

The VEV $\langle 0\rvert\psi\lvert 0\rangle$, or (perhaps more precisely) $\langle 0\rvert\psi(\mathbf{x})\lvert 0\rangle$, is then a scalar-valued function of position: it maps every point $\mathbf{x}$ to the vacuum expectation value of the operator corresponding to that point.